# Using recursion to create a linked list from a list

Tags: python, list, linked-list

how would one go about using recursion in order to take a list of random values and make it a linked list? Where each value is a node. As of right now, i've tried implementing the following...

```
def pyListToMyList(pylst):
        lists = mkMyList()
        lists.head = pyListToMyListRec(pylst)
        return lists

def pyListToMyList(pylst):            
        if pylst:
                return mkEmptyNode()
        else:
                return mkNode(pylst[0], pyLstToMyListRec(pylst[1:]))
```

The problem is the the else statement which returns an error saying that the index is out of range.

Comment: I'll edit the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def pyListToMyList(pylst):            
    if not pylst:
        return mkEmptyNode()
    else:
        return mkNode(pylst[0], pyLstToMyListRec(pylst[1:]))
```

EDIT: Though this is O(n^2) because of all the list copying.

I would do

```
def pyListToMyList(pylst, i=0):
    if i > len(pylst):
        return mkEmptyNode()
    else:
        return mkNode(pylst[i], pyLstToMyListRec(pylst, i+1))
```

or even more efficient and less likely to overflow stack (though this does not use recursion):

```
def pyListToMyList(pylst):
    lst = mkEmptyNode()
    for x in reversed(pylist):
        lst = mkNode(x, lst)
    return lst
```